# FoxPro - DAO syntax to UPDATE table from another table

Tags: vb6, sql-update, dao, foxpro

Am having problems trying to run a simple UPDATE from another table on FoxPro 2.5 tables, using VB6 and DAO. But am baffled, as I can find no syntax for this which is accepted.

I am trying to UPDATE a field in file TEST.DBF with the value of a looked up code in file JOBS.DBF.

This code generates error 3075 "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'jobs.rcode FROM test INNER JOIN jobs ON test.jobcode = jobs.code'.":

```
Dim dbsWork As Database
Dim qrd As DAO.QueryDef
Dim szSqlString As String

Set dbsWork = OpenDatabase(szWorkDir, False, False, "FoxPro 2.5")
szSqlString = "UPDATE test SET test.mask = jobs.rcode FROM test INNER JOIN jobs ON test.jobcode = jobs.code "
Set qrd = dbsWork.CreateQueryDef("", szSqlString)
qrd.Execute

Set qrd = Nothing
Set dbsWork = Nothing
```

What syntax should I use please?

Answer (score 1):

Try using correlated query like this

```
UPDATE test
SET mask = (SELECT rcode FROM jobs WHERE code = test.jobcode)
WHERE jobcode IN (SELECT code FROM jobs)
```

Comment: Thanks @wqw, but this did not work either. I know I should have noted down the error message, but I was so fed up with the limitations I found of using FoxPro data with DAO, that I abandoned using FoxPro data. Instead I chose to import the data into an Access MDB file and use DAO on this - as I know this will work.